# Validation not working on multipart/form-data body

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, joi

Trying to validate the body of a registration request for an assistant, which is of the form multipart/form-data due to having an avatar attached.

Did some research and I came out with this
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/693

but don't really know to it works so far

This is my code in Joi

```
const Joi = require('joi');


module.exports = {
    passwordStandard(req, res, next) {
        const schema = {
            password: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,32}$/).required()
        }

        const {
            error
        } = Joi.validate({
            password: req.body.password
        }, schema);
        if (error) {
            const err = error.details[0].message
            res.status(400).json({
                err,
                errmsg: 'Invalid password',
                message: '<ul class=\'error\'> ' +
                    '<li>password must not contain special characters</li>' +
                    '<li>password must be atmost 5 characters long</li>' +
                    '</ul>'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
}
```

I get password is require with a 400 bad request and the errors define above.

The error 400 to be returned as the validation did not pass.

Comment: Did you confirm that the req.body.password is not undefined or null? What is the  message error?

Comment: Since I made the field in joi to be required
Here is the error
    "err": "\"password\" is required", 
More like password is null

Comment: So you want the joi to pass when the password is null? If so, you can add .allow(null) after your .required()

Comment: No sorry let me rephrase, I'm passing the password but Joi is giving me a error of password require with mean Joi can't access the password form postman and so it considers it null but all the other fields are good.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LSs_WZRL8eGAmVIRyNvM6Nw90cxUQAiT/view?usp=sharing 

This is my request with all it's params

Comment: Your password is probably inside req.payload.password and not in the req.body.password, that's why I asked you to confirm what's inside your req.body in order to discard this possibility.

Comment: Ok thanks let me try that.

Comment: When I use req.payload.password, I get undefine property.


"message": "Cannot read property 'password' of undefined"

Comment: I did a console.log(req) in Joi and I found out that the body of my req is an empty object. and all this started when I added Multer, and when I put the multer middleware first it works but if there was an error when validating a new user, the image saves in the provided folder so I decided to save image only when the user has been registered to the system, and now am getting this error.

Comment: You need to figure it out why your req is an empty object, it is not supposed to be. I guess your problem is not related with Joi, because it seems right.

Comment: yeah I figure that too 

thanks...